# Convert PDF to Jpg with ghostscript from stdin(string) to stdout

Tags: php, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert a multipage pdf to jpg with ghostscript in PHP. The command right now looks something like this:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dJPEGQ=100 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r72 -sOutputFile=- some.pdf
```

What I want is to find a way to input the pdf as string which looks something like this: '%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj, etc.' and output all pages to stdout. Providing an actual pdf file to the command works pretty fine, but it returns a single page. If opting for file writing there is an option p%03d.jpg to get all the pages, but I need it to be dumped to temp/memory. From what I understand you need to use pipes to get this to work. I made something with proc_open() but without any success because I don't know how to pass the string to the pipe.

```
$args = [
    '-dBATCH',
    '-sDEVICE=jpeg',
    '-dNOPAUSE',
    '-dSAFER',
    '-dJPEGQ=100',
    '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4',
    '-dTextAlphaBits=4',
    '-r72',
    '-sOutputFile=-',
    $path . '/some.pdf'// this should be passed as string stdin
];

$descr = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe','w']
];
$pipes = array();
$args = implode(' ', $args);
$commd = "gs -q $args";

$process = proc_open($commd, $descr, $pipes);

$response = '';

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fputs($pipes[0], $pdf);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    while ($f = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        $response .= $f;
    }

    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
}

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' . base64_encode($response) . '" />';
```

**Update:**
Found the solution for the input. It's a dash instead of the last argument representing the input file. The multipage output still remains an issue.

Comment: Hello @Calin instead of doing your own implementation, i highly recommand you to use abtraction library such as : [ghostscript-PHP](https://github.com/alchemy-fr/Ghostscript-PHP) for GhostScript or [imagick](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.imagick.php)

Comment: Hi @Yanis-git. Thanks for your answer. I want to avoid Imagick because it's really slow on a reasonable resolution, for the other one it's not adapted fro this, it's very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a PDF file in memory using Ghostscript.

Ghostscript only processes PDF files from disk. If you pipe the input from stdin all that happens is that Ghostscript creates a temporary file, stores the PDF in that, and then renders the temporary file. This is because PDF files inherently require the ability to seek randomly within the file.

So in fact by sending the file via stdin you're just moving the creation of the temporary file to being done inside Ghostscript instead of doing it yourself. If you think you are somehow improving performance by doing this, you are mistaken.

If you specify `-` (stdout) as the output file then **all** the output is sent to stdout. If there's more than one page, then both pages are sent to the output (what else could it do ?). Its up to you to figure out where each page ends and split it up.

If you omit the `-q` and look at what gets sent to stdout (eg by redirecting it to a file) you will see that the usual Ghostscript boilerplate is sent at the start. If you further omit the `-dNOPAUSE` (note you will need to press 'return' for each page and you won't be prompted, so just hammer the key a bit) and then look at the output you will see that each page is separated by

```
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

So you can see that each page is sent, and its up to you to figure out where each JPEG ends.

I'm not sure what else you were expecting to happen, given that you are sending multiple pages of output to stdout.

Comment: thanks for this infos. Writing in temporary file it's ok. I didn't wanted to explicitly create the actual pdf the pass it to gs that's why I opted for stdin(I'm not sure that's the correct expression). So my stdin issue is solved, but regarding the stdout I can't find any jpg "separator" >>showpage, ... in the output. Beside of this, rendering the output with <img src="data:image/jpg;base64... will display only the image of the first page. Using something like -sOutputFile=$path/%03d.jpeg is writing them all, but again I need -sOutputFile=-

Comment: If you want to see the 'showpage' message then you need to remove the -q and -dNOPAUSE from the command line, as I said. As I also said, if you send everything to stdout then its going to be up to you to identify the end of each image. So you can do what you want (send the data to stdou), but you're going to have to do some work yourself to recover the individual images.

Comment: can you tell how reliable is to process the output string by a pattern based an the actual command output, with other words are there any chances that the output can change, don't know maybe in a newer version?

Comment: The output is a JPEG image, wrapped up as a JFIF file, its up to you how you determine the beginning and end of each image.

Comment: I managed to do that and it's working like a charm, but my concern is if ghostscript can change it's output format, because if so I have a second option to temporary store the images and convert them into strings which it's reliable but it's kind of useless to do that, string->image->string. Maybe forgot to mention that I need to send the response as base64 encoded string. Anyway thanks for your help once again.

Comment: If you choose a JPEG device, then the output will always be a valid JPEG image in a JFIF file. Its possible that the actual details of the file will change (we might store an ICC profile in the file now for example), but the output will still be a JFIF-compliant JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

i have test this code locally and is working for me :

I'am using [passthru](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.passthru.php) to direct output answer, and play around [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-get-contents.php) to capture a

```
<?php

$command = "/path/to/gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dJPEGQ=100 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r72 -sOutputFile=- ./someFile.pdf";

// Capture output on buffer.
ob_start();

// Will automatically output answer of your command
passthru($command);
// you get buffered output.
$response = ob_get_contents();
// Flush buffer.
ob_end_clean();

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' . base64_encode($response) . '" />';
```

Comment: Yes, this might be a good solution if you have the file on disk, but as mentioned I want to pass it trough a pipe.

Comment: i don't understand what do you want to acheive with pipe

Comment: I can't pass an actual file, but a string so I have to pass it trough a pipe

Comment: oh i see, is it possible for you to store your string in file temporary then delete it when you have finish your traitement ?